# xaml debugging application

Tags: wpf, debugging, xaml

I need to debug xaml and i am looking for some application for that .

Need for recommendations.

Snoop not manages to find my application while i am trying use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had great results with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) but you might want to check if you are running your app with elevated permissions eg as administrator as this will prevent it showing up in the list of applications inside Snoop - from snoop codeplex page

> *Why Aren’t My Apps Showing Up in the App Chooser? One question that comes
>   up all the time is the situation where
>   the application you are trying to
>   Snoop, isn't appearing in the
>   application chooser (i.e. the  combo
>   box that lists the processes you can
>   Snoop). This is more than likely a
>   situation where the application you
>   are trying to Snoop is running
>   elevated (as Administrator). In order
>   to Snoop these applications, you will
>   also need to run Snoop elevated (as
>   Administrator).*

Also if your xaml is Silverlight then it looks like the only options is [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/)

Comment: already tried this administrator thing , not solved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Visual Tree Visualizer' from VS 10 (VS C#/VB.NET) 2010 Express. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx